# How does Magento store deleted products in database

Tags: magento

I'm running a script that exports magento products in an xml. I do the query using SQL connections and selecting all attributes. It there a way or how can I find information of deleted products in a magento database?

Comment: No there is none for that.

Comment: Try using this,http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/yireo-trashcan.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only way to find out is to have a list of all existing products or products that have existed and compare them against current dataset. Other way would be never delete a product but mark them as out of stock or inactive

Comment: so if i deleted a product, there will be no way i can know in database, like flagging the product?

Comment: no , as that's the point of deleting and there's no "trash can" functionality in Magento. Otherwise don't delete and mark as inactive instead